# Issue using strtok to validate a user-entered date in C

Tags: c, validation, token, tokenize, delimiter

I am trying to validate a user-entered date in C. However, I can't seem to get strtok to separate by the "-" delimiter. For example, I want to verify that a user has entered a date correctly in the format mm/dd/yyyy-hh:mm where hh is the 2 digit representation of the hour and mm is minutes past the hour in 2 digits also.

This is what I have been doing.

```
 char* input[] //--user input

 char* token[];//-- used to seperate each portion and verify them individually.

 token = strtok(input, " /-:"); //-- token is now the mm.
 ...todo

token = strtok(NULL, "/"); //---token is now the dd.
...todo

token = strtok(NULL, "/"); //---token is now the yyyy.
...todo
```

I've been using prinf token every step to verify and everything runs smoothly until I try to get to the hh.

HERE'S THE ISSUE: When I try to call

```
token = strtok(NULL, "-") //for the hours in a valid input
```

the token is NULL. within todo I verify that token is not null but in this case it always is even when I enter a valid date.

Comment: `char * input[]` is the declaration for an array of pointers (if you add a semicolon ,that is) , which is probably not what you want. Please post real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using

```
if ( sscanf ( input, "%d/%d/%d-%d:%d", &mm, &dd, &yyyy, &hr, &m) == 5)
```

The format string scans an int, a `'/'`, an int, a `'/'`, an int, a `'-'`, an int, a `':'`, and an int. If successful scan of all items, the return is 5.